# Does an exponential series expansion exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, transformation

I know we can expand a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with a power series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n,
$$
where we can find find $\{a_n\}$ given $f$ using its derivatives about $0$. What I would like to know is whether an "exponential series" exists for $f$. That is, is there a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n e^{x n},
$$
and if so, how would we find $b_n$ given a general $f$? Are there conditions on $f$ for which no sequence $\{b_n\}$ can exist?

Edit: To be clear, $x$ here is real, not imaginary, so this is not a Fourier series, and the $e^{xn}$ functions are not an orthonormal basis. Obviously some trivial series do exist, such as $f(x) = e^x$ for $b_n = \delta_{n1}$, but what about more interesting functions such as $f(x) = e^{x^2}$?

Comment: Do you know about Fourier series?

Comment: There's a rich theory of these when you allow these exponentials to be complex. These are then called Fourier series, and are written with respect to a complete orthonormal basis $e^{2 \pi i n}$ for $L^2$. The inner product here is $\langle f,g \rangle = \int f(x) \overline{g(x)}$. Then extracting coefficients is simply taking the inner product against this orthonormal basis. I'm not sure of anything interesting if you need these to be real exponentials.

Comment: I should have clarified---I specifically am asking about real-valued $x$; I'll edit the original question.

Comment: Provided $\{b_n\}$ decays quickly enough, there will be at least some values of $x$ for which the series converges. An example is $b_n = \frac{1}{n!}$, which gives $f(x) = e^{e^x}$.

Comment: Wouldn't this be possible iff $f\circ \log$ is analytic?

Comment: I was thinking similarly to @Reveillark. I think the functions you get this way are exactly functions of the form $f(e^x)$ for some real-analytic $f$.

Comment: I think this is the answer that I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such an expansion exists whenever $f$ is *periodic*. That is, say $f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$ for every $x$. Obviously $2\pi$ is just a convention here. By rescaling, you can make it be whatever you want.

Then the [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) associated to $f$ is the sum

$$f(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

Under relatively general conditions (that are still technical enough for me to not want to mention) such a series exists, but periodicity is the important one. We can see periodicity is necessary since each of the $e^{2 \pi i n x}$ are periodic.

In much the same way that a taylor series lets you write $f$ in terms of its derivatives, a fourier series lets your write $f$ in terms of its "harmonics". Importantly, we still have a nice formula for the coefficients:

$$a_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2 \pi i n x} \cdot f ~ \mathrm{d}x$$

In many contexts, these $a_n$ are called $\hat{f}(n)$, and you'll see that notation scattered through the literature. This is a field that is very deep *and* very broad, so it should be exciting to get some exposure to it!
You can find a relatively polite treatment of the subject in [these](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Etl/fa/fa_notes.pdf) notes by Tom Leinster

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just amended the question to be clear that I'm specifically interested in _real_ exponential functions, not complex exponentials. Unfortunately, the Fourier series is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I will leave my answer up so that others don't make the same mistake. I suspect many people will reach for Fourier series upon seeing your question. In part because they're very useful and commonly known, and in part because I'm not sure if a better answer exists. I'm exited to be proven wrong, though!